# Crafting a Check Constraint that Depends on Another Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working in Oracle.  I've got two tables, a master table with an ID columns and a detail table, with an ID column, a foreign key to the master table and a name column.

```
MASTER
--------
ID
```

formatting break

```
DETAIL
-------------
ID
MASTER_ID
NAME
```

I want all the child details of a given master to have unique names.  Name is not unique among the details, though.  Two details with different masters may have the same name.

I think I can do this with a check constraint, but I'm struggling with how to phrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you want a `check` constraint.  It sounds like you want a unique constraint

```
alter table detail_table
  add constraint name_uniq_within_master unique( master_id, name );
```

That would prevent you from having two rows with the same `name` and `master_id` but would allow rows with the same `name` and different `master_id` values.